# How to show the number of each row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rows

Hello I want to show the index number of each row in the table I tried with for loop but I had no success can you tell me how to do that ?
I need a logic that return the number of each row in the line "case 0: return getRowCount();" it return the total of rows only

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

UsersDao ud = new usersDao();
private List<Users> users;

public TableModel() throws Exception {
    this.users = (ArrayList<Users>)ud.getUsersList();
}   

private DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return users.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 10;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Users u = users.get(rowIndex);
    switch(columnIndex){
        case 0: return getRowCount();
        case 1: return u.getName();
        case 2: return u.getAge();
        case 3: return u.getGender();
        default: return "";     
    }
}

public String getColumnName(int column){
    switch(column){
        case 0: return "NO";
        case 1: return "NAME";
        case 2: return "AGE";
        case 3: return "GENDER";
        default: return "";
    }
}

public void addUser(Users u){
    users.add(u);
    fireTableRowsInserted(users.size()-1, users.size()-1);
}

public void deletePatient(Users u){
    users.remove(p);
    fireTableRowsInserted(users.size()-1, users.size()-1);
}
```

}

Comment: What prevents you from using `rowIndex` ?

Comment: Yep `case 0: return rowIndex;`

Comment: I did case 0: return u; and I did not works lol thank so much ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a problem in getValueAt

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Users u = users.get(rowIndex);
    switch(columnIndex){
        case 0: return rowIndex; // return rowIndex rather than the total number of rows
        case 1: return u.getName();
        case 2: return u.getAge();
        case 3: return u.getGender();
        default: return "";     
    }
}
```